# How to secure endpoint without login/password for mailchimp subscription from SPA Landing Page?

Tags: rest, security, single-page-application, nestjs

I have `nestjs` api with endpoint `/subscribe` for users to be able to subscribe on mailchimp.
How I can secure endpoint, if possible, to receive only requests from frontend SPA(done in vue.js)?
I have tried to setup csrf middleware and add special route `/form` which retursn `csrf` with idea to call this endpoint on page load to obtain csrf and then use it with post payload on submission of subscription but not suer if this s a good idea? Also added some throtling mechanism. 
What is a proper way to secure that endpoint for subscription?

Comment: As far as I can see, your `/subscribe` endpoint is a public endpoint, so what do you want to protect it against?

Comment: @kkkkkkk at least some recaptcha colud help. Not sure for any other idea ..... maybe to introduce some 2 steps process .. on the first page some token to be generated and send in the request on the second step and then you should verify on first step recaptcha and on second some key, like csrf?